# jquery.tools / jquery.min conflict

Tags: jquery

I am trying to install two jquery plugins, one require

```
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

and the other require

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but this provokes a conflict disabling one of them (the obviously the second)

Is there a way of going around this?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: It would be best to re-download jQuery Tools without jQuery included within it and only including jQuery once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jQuery, then jQuery tools without jQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Kevin B;s advice I went to [jQuerytools](http://jquerytools.org/download/) and re-downloaded jQuery Tools **without** jQuery included.

Now everything works like a charm